# unable to set kerberos authentication in mssql 2014 express

Tags: sql-server-2014, kerberos

Hello I've recently installed MS SQL 2014 Express in MS Server 2016 Essential
I wanted to use Kerberos authentication so I've run through many pages but whenever I'm trying authentication always says NTLM.
I have only one server where I'm running AD and SQL and this is physical one.

What was done:

1. service account security settings:

   - granted rights to read/write public information
2. service account delegation -> for specific services use Kerberos only:

   - all listed as MSsqlsvc Service Type
3. SQL Server Configuration Manager

   - Network congfiguration -> Enable TCP/IP
   - Port changed from dynamic to static one
4. Component Services -> Local DTC

   - Enabled Network DTC access
   - Allow remote clients and admins
   - Allow Inbound and Outbound
   - Mutual authentication required

```
    C:\Users\sql_svc>setspn -l SOMEDOMAIN\sql_svc
        Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=sql_svc,CN=Users,DC=SOMEDOMAIN,DC=local:
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER_NAME.SOMEDOMAIN.local:58568
        MSSQLSvc/SERVER_NAME.SOMEDOMAIN.local:SQL_INSTANCE_NAME
```

Kerberos Configuration Manager says status GOOD for SPN and 'No Obvious delegation issues' in Delegation tab

I'm running out of ideas. Any ideas much appreciated

query used to check connection type:

```sql
select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid
```

Comment: Are you connecting from the server itself? If so, the connection will use Shared Memory instead of TCP, and that will push you to NTLM. Add net_transport to your query to check: `select auth_scheme, net_transport from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = @@spid`.

Comment: you were right as I was connecting from sql server. Query siad that it uses shared memory. So I've disabled shared memory and named pipes, connected from different PC and now it shows net_transport as TCP but auth_scheme is still NTLM. PC that I'm trying now is not within domain so i used command `runas /netonly /user:somedomain\sql_svc ssms.exe`

Comment: If the client PC is not in the same domain as the SQL server, I don't think you'll be able to get a Kerberos connection. Do you have a client PC in the domain that you can use to test with?

Comment: I will have in a few days. I will check than, Thank you for suggestions!